# non standard shape antialiased WPF window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, antialiasing, region

I'm using C# to create a non standard shape WPF window, and because of some problems with "*AllowTransparency=True*", I used **CreateRoundRectRgn**, **CreateEllipticRgn** and **SetWindowRgn** win32 API [Region functions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/rgnguide.aspx), but there's a problem cause the edges are not smooth as you can see in the picture here http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/206/sampley.png:

[alt text http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/206/sampley.png](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/206/sampley.png)

How can I achieve antialiasing for the edges to look more smooth ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, anti-aliased edges require per-pixel alpha channel (what AllowTransparency=true does) - but when you turn that option on (either using AllowTransparency or by invoking the Win32 API, the result is the same) you get into a whole lot of trouble - like you already discovered.